# Variable value change with "ifelse"

Tags: r

I want to change variable "month" to a new variable "season". 
I tried two ways like below, but it seems like there are some errors in my code.

```
train_fd<-train_fd %>% mutate(season = ifelse(month <= 2 & month == 12,"winter",
                                         ifelse(month <= 5 & month > 3,"spring",
                                                ifelse(month <= 9 & month > 6,"summer","fall"))))

train_fd <- within(train_fd,
                  {
                    season = character(0)
                    season[month <= 2 & month == 12] = "winter"
                    season[month <= 5 & month >= 3] = "spring"
                    season[month <= 9 & month >= 6] = "summer"
                    season[month == 10 & month == 11] = "fall"
                    season = factor(season, level = c("winter","spring","summer","fall"))
                  })
```

I expect the output of level to be `c("winter","spring","summer","fall")`, but the actual output is level

```
c("winter", "fall")
```

Comment: Please read [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (and ask a question that is likely to get answered).

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using `%in%` operator -

```
ifelse(month %in% c(1,2,12), "winter",
       ifelse(month %in% c(3,4,5), "spring",
              ifelse(month %in% c(6,7,8,9), "summer", "fall")))
```

Would also suggest you to look at `?case_when()` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I would save myself a ton of trouble doing an explicit dictionary:

```
m2s <- c( rep("winter", 2), 
          rep("spring", 3), 
          rep("summer", 4), 
          rep("fall", 2), "winter)
```

And now you can simply

```
train_fd$season <- m2s[ train_fd$month ]
```

Note the problems in your first approach:

- `month <= 2 & month == 12` always returns `FALSE`, because you used `&` instead of `|`; therefore January, February and December all become "fall";
- `month <= 5 & month > 3` what if `month == 3`? Then March is fall...
- `month <= 9 & month > 6` again, June becomes fall.

Your second approach replicates some of these errors (such as `&` for winter) and add new ones (such as condition `month == 10 & month == 11`, which always returns `FALSE`). I have not the slightest idea, however, how you can get `winter` as an output level in any of the approaches: this is not possible.

Bottom line is: multilayered conditionals are prone to typos.